# Derivation of Gaussian Newton

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, gaussian

The question is simply about the derivation of Gaussian-Newton in solving a non-linear optimization problems, specifically in CS.
The object function is simply $\parallel f(x) \parallel_2^2$.
To know how the incremental $\Delta x$ is determined, it firstly transformed via the Taylor expansion
$$ f(x + \Delta x) = f(x) + f'(x)\Delta x + \frac{1}{2!}f''(x){\Delta x}^2 + \cdots$$ (all these $x$ are vectors)
By taking the 1st order of this expansion into the object function, we get $$\parallel f(x) + \mathbf{J}(x)\Delta x \parallel_2^2$$
Then we get this equation expanded to be like
$$\begin{aligned} & (f+\mathbf{J} \Delta)^\mathrm{T} (f+\mathbf{J} \Delta) = f^\mathrm{T}f + f^\mathrm{T} \mathbf{J}\Delta + \Delta^\mathrm{T} \mathbf{J}^\mathrm{T}f+\Delta^\mathrm{T} \mathbf{J}^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{J}\Delta \\
\end{aligned}$$
Then, we calculate the derivative of $\Delta$ to the one above and get
$$f^\mathrm{T} \mathbf{J}+ \mathbf{J}^\mathrm{T}f+\mathbf{J}^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{J}\Delta+\Delta^\mathrm{T} \mathbf{J}^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{J}$$
This is what I am not sure, because I cannot get the result that $\mathbf{J}f + \mathbf{J}\mathbf{J}^\mathrm{T}\Delta$.
Maybe I remember wrong rules of matrix calculation.

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Your expansion is not written correctly (you have to use the Taylor series in more dimensions):
\begin{align}
f({\bf x}+{\bf h})=f({\bf x})+{\bf J}^{\text T}{\bf h}+o({\bf h})
\end{align}
I denote ${\bf h}$ instead of $\triangle$, because ${\bf h}$ is a vector. Also $f$ is a scalar function, therefore $f^{\text{T}}=f$.
Also note that ${\bf J}^{\text{T}}{\bf h}={\bf{h}}^{\text{T}}{\bf J}$. You have to evaluate one half of the quadrat:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}(f+{\bf J}^{\text{T}}{\bf h})(f+{\bf J}^{\text{T}}{\bf h})=\frac{f^2}{2}+f\underbrace{{\bf J}^{\text{T}}{\bf h}}_{{\bf{h}}^{\text{T}}{\bf J}}+\frac{1}{2}{\bf{h}}^{\text{T}}{\bf J}{\bf J}^{\text{T}}{\bf h}
\end{align}
Derivative of the second and third term can be obtained form a general definition of the first derivative
\begin{align}
a({\bf h}+\text{d}{\bf h})=a({\bf h})+(\text{d}{\bf h})^{\text{T}}\frac{\partial a}{\partial {\bf h}}+o(\text{d}{\bf h})
\end{align}
The second term gives ${\bf h}^{\text{T}}f{\bf J}$ i.e. derivative $f{\bf J}$, the last term gives derivative ${\bf JJ}^{\text{T}}{\bf h}$, which is seen from
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}({\bf{h}}+{\text{d}\bf{h}})^{\text{T}}{\bf{JJ}}^{\text{T}}({\bf{h}}+{\text{d}\bf{h}})=_{\text{linear terms only}} \frac{1}{2}\left[({\text{d}\bf{h}})^{\text{T}}{\bf{JJ}}^{\text{T}}{\bf h} + {\bf h}^{\text{T}}{\bf{JJ}}^{\text{T}}({\text{d}\bf{h}})\right]={\bf h}^{\text{T}}{\bf{JJ}}^{\text{T}}({\text{d}\bf{h}})=({\text{d}\bf{h}})^{\text{T}}{\bf{JJ}}^{\text{T}}{\bf h}
\end{align}
where the last equality is due to symmetry of ${\bf JJ}^{\text{T}}$. All together:
\begin{align}
f{\bf J}+{\bf JJ}^{\text{T}}{\bf h}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Gauss-Newton method is applied
to minimize objective function
with the form
$\phi(\mathbf{x}) = \| \mathbf{r}(\mathbf{x}) \|^2$.

At $k$-th iterate,
GN approximates
the term using Taylor expansion
$$
\mathbf{r}_{GN}(\mathbf{x})
=
\mathbf{r}_k + 
\mathbf{J}_k
\left( \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_k \right) 
\simeq
\mathbf{r}(\mathbf{x})
$$
with the notations
$\mathbf{r}_k = \mathbf{r}(\mathbf{x}_k)$
and the Jacobian
$\mathbf{J}_k = \mathbf{J}(\mathbf{x}_k)$.

The differential writes now
$
d\phi_{GN} =
2\mathbf{r}_{GN}(\mathbf{x}):
\mathbf{J}_k d\mathbf{x}
$
and thus the derivative is
$$
\frac{\partial \phi_{GN}}{\partial \mathbf{x}}
=
2\mathbf{J}_k^T \mathbf{r}_{GN}(\mathbf{x})
$$

Setting the derivative to zero yields
the GN update
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbf{x}_{k+1}
&=&
\mathbf{x}_k -
\left( \mathbf{J}_k^T \mathbf{J}_k \right)^{-1}
\mathbf{J}_k^T \mathbf{r}_k
\end{eqnarray*}